# undestand Snowflake encryption results

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run on Snowflake this command, for example:

```
select encrypt_raw(to_binary(hex_encode('239.239.239.239')), 
                                   to_binary(hex_encode('1234567890123456')), 
                                   to_binary(hex_encode('123456789012'))
              )
```

I get this result:

```
{ "ciphertext": "83425786EAA26D2695C2229B640263", "iv": "313233343536373839303132", "tag": "F377ACE5BFA744D22599F9A1F274B840" }
```

What in this result is the encrypted value itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our docs:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/encrypt_raw.html#returns

```
The second field is the ciphertext (encrypted value) of the value_to_encrypt.
```

Comment: how do I get this specific field out of the results? I need to insert it into a table.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

```
select V:ciphertext from (select encrypt_raw(to_binary(hex_encode('239.239.239.239')), 
                                   to_binary(hex_encode('1234567890123456')), 
                                   to_binary(hex_encode('123456789012'))
              ) as v);
```

gets me this output:
[image]